# Using Key like "[]Server" into sortedDictionary, but why? 

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand and probably reuse part of DevExpress Demo code to save simple settings into ini file. I know I can use .NET System.Configuration doing what I want. Just for a smallish project, simple save it as a text file seem more flexible and light-weighted, at least that is what it seems.

Anyway, while I am playing with it, I am trying to understand why the code I am reading trying to add key as "[]Server" and "[]DBFormat" as key name. They do that for a reason I can not understand yet, I could probably use some help here.

Here is the Code I think relevant:

```
 public class IniFile {
        SortedDictionary<string, string> data = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        ...
        public void Load(string path) {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) {
                string folder = "[]";
                while(!sr.EndOfStream) {
                    string s = sr.ReadLine().Trim();
                    if(s.Length == 0 || s[0] == ';') continue;
                    if(s[0] == '[') {
                        folder = s;
                        continue;
                    }
                    string key, value;
                    int delim = s.IndexOf('=');
                    if(delim < 0) {
                        key = folder + s.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
                        value = string.Empty;
                    } else {
                        key = folder + s.Remove(delim).TrimEnd().Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
                        value = s.Substring(delim + 1).TrimStart();
                    }
                    if(!data.ContainsKey(key)) data.Add(key, value);
                    else data[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        ...
        public void Save(string path) {
            using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)) {
                string folder = "[]";
                foreach(string key in data.Keys) {
                    int delim = key.IndexOf(']');
                    string keyFolder = key.Remove(delim + 1);
                    string keyName = key.Substring(delim + 1);
                    if(keyFolder != folder) {
                        folder = keyFolder;
                        sw.WriteLine(folder);
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine(keyName + " = " + data[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        void AddRawValue(string key, string value) {
            key = key.Trim();
            value = value.Trim();
            int folderBegin = key.IndexOf('[');
            int folderEnd = key.IndexOf(']');
            if(folderBegin != 0 || folderEnd < 0) throw new ArgumentException("key");
            data.Add(key, value);
        }
```

And here is part of the ini file itself:

```
DBFormat = "Mdb"
Login = "admin"
Password = ""
Server = "(localhost)"
```

Obvious, they go though the trouble to add [] into keyname for some reason, but end up not using it in the demo data. I am think they are using string inside [] to group settings?

Comment: Not sure I agree that using some (inscrutable) demo code from some 3rd party is easier or simpler than using the configuration system baked into the BCL.

Comment: I've gotta say, that is really ugly code.

Comment: Based on the quality of this code, I suggest that you not waste your time trying to understand it, and instead find another source for code samples.

Comment: Agree, I don't like the code myself, and in general not big fan of devExpress. But Boss keep on buying their product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only skimmed it, but I'd imagine the intent might have been `"[section]setting"` so `"[]setting"` would represent a setting *not* in a section. Look how easy it is to get values, just a single string will do! (There seems to be confusion between a "section" and a "folder" -- which might be an above-par variable name for that code...)

Then again, *I could be way off* as I only invested about 10 seconds of time on that tripe >:)

Happy coding.

Comment: In some circles, every hierarchical storage system calls its containers "folders".  Probably because they found it too hard to keep directories vs sections vs hives vs keys vs tables all straight.

Comment: Yeah, image if the original programmer could give the variable a better name, how it could save me time and headache for the guessing game.